# in the handler of SetUnhandledExceptionFilter how to print a stacktrace?

Tags: c++, winapi

When unhandled exception occured i want to print a stacktrace instead of just terminating. I've tried to do that using `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`:

```
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(UnhandledException);
    ...
LONG WINAPI UnhandledException(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS exceptionInfo)  
{  
    printf("An exception occurred which wasn't handled!\nCode: 0x%08X\nAddress: 0x%08X",   
        exceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode,  
        exceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionAddress);
    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;  
}
```

This code, i've found, works fine. However there are no addition information because `ExceptionCode` and `ExceptionAddress` are printed in system "Event Viewer" anyway.
If it is possible to print a full stack trace so I can determine the exact point where exception occured?

I've found this code https://code.google.com/p/m0d-s0beit-sa/source/browse/src/main.cpp?r=9ceb4fec21d647b169c72851d7882bef2b9c5a8a It partly solves my problem. Only method where exception occured is printed. But type of exception and line number is not printed.

Comment: You can always let yourself be inspired by http://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/ or simply use it for its convenient liberal license ;) ... I think it has exactly what you want. Line number and so on are btw things that come when you load a post-mortem dump and have full PDBs. Something the end user likely won't have anyway.

Comment: @0xC0000022L it's nice to have solution without third-party libriries. all i want right now is to print a stack trace. and I will throw this got after a while as I'm porting to Linux.

Comment: if you consider even MS's libs as third-party (they are required and need to be installed to interpret the symbols unless you read Sven Schreiber's *Undocumented Windows 2000 Secrets*) you're out of luck. Otherwise you can still reuse parts of this stuff and simply link it into your binary. The BSD license only requires attribution. Something you have to care about even less when it's for internal use only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's some stack-walk code for Windows I wrote some years ago. Here's the kind of output it produces:

```
Walking stack.
0       DebugBreak
1       ThreadFunc2     e:\c\source\stackwalk2a.cpp(72)
2       ThreadFunc1     e:\c\source\stackwalk2a.cpp(79)
3       TargetThread    e:\c\source\stackwalk2a.cpp(86)
4       BaseThreadInitThunk
5       RtlUserThreadStart
End of stack walk.
```

The main thing that's missing is anything about the exception type. If you're talking about a native structured/vectored exception, I'm pretty sure that should be retrievable too. Retrieving types of C++ exceptions might be a little more difficult (but I'm not really sure -- it might be pretty easy).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iterator>

#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dbghelp.lib")

// Some versions of imagehlp.dll lack the proper packing directives themselves
// so we need to do it.
#pragma pack( push, before_imagehlp, 8 )
#include <imagehlp.h>
#pragma pack( pop, before_imagehlp )

struct module_data {
    std::string image_name;
    std::string module_name;
    void *base_address;
    DWORD load_size;
};
typedef std::vector<module_data> ModuleList;

HANDLE thread_ready;

bool show_stack(std::ostream &, HANDLE hThread, CONTEXT& c);
DWORD __stdcall TargetThread( void *arg );
void ThreadFunc1();
void ThreadFunc2();
DWORD Filter( EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ep );
void *load_modules_symbols( HANDLE hProcess, DWORD pid );

int main( void ) {
    DWORD thread_id;

    thread_ready = CreateEvent( NULL, false, false, NULL );

    HANDLE thread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, TargetThread, NULL, 0, &thread_id );

    WaitForSingleObject( thread_ready, INFINITE );
    CloseHandle(thread_ready);
    return 0;
}

// if you use C++ exception handling: install a translator function
// with set_se_translator(). In the context of that function (but *not*
// afterwards), you can either do your stack dump, or save the CONTEXT
// record as a local copy. Note that you must do the stack dump at the
// earliest opportunity, to avoid the interesting stack-frames being gone
// by the time you do the dump.
DWORD Filter(EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ep) {
    HANDLE thread;

    DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentThread(),
        GetCurrentProcess(), &thread, 0, false, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
    std::cout << "Walking stack.";
    show_stack(std::cout, thread, *(ep->ContextRecord));
    std::cout << "\nEnd of stack walk.\n";
    CloseHandle(thread);

    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

void ThreadFunc2() {
    __try { DebugBreak(); }
    __except (Filter(GetExceptionInformation())) {  }
    SetEvent(thread_ready);
}

void ThreadFunc1(void (*f)()) {
    f();
}

// We'll do a few levels of calls from our thread function so 
//     there's something on the stack to walk...
//
DWORD __stdcall TargetThread(void *) {
    ThreadFunc1(ThreadFunc2);
    return 0;
}

class SymHandler { 
    HANDLE p;
public:
    SymHandler(HANDLE process, char const *path=NULL, bool intrude = false) : p(process) { 
        if (!SymInitialize(p, path, intrude)) 
            throw(std::logic_error("Unable to initialize symbol handler"));
    }
    ~SymHandler() { SymCleanup(p); }
};

#ifdef _M_X64
STACKFRAME64 init_stack_frame(CONTEXT c) {
    STACKFRAME64 s;
    s.AddrPC.Offset = c.Rip;
    s.AddrPC.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
    s.AddrStack.Offset = c.Rsp;
    s.AddrStack.Mode = AddrModeFlat;    
    s.AddrFrame.Offset = c.Rbp;
    s.AddrFrame.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
    return s;
}
#else
STACKFRAME64 init_stack_frame(CONTEXT c) {
    STACKFRAME64 s;
    s.AddrPC.Offset = c.Eip;
    s.AddrPC.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
    s.AddrStack.Offset = c.Esp;
    s.AddrStack.Mode = AddrModeFlat;    
    s.AddrFrame.Offset = c.Ebp;
    s.AddrFrame.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
    return s;
}
#endif

void sym_options(DWORD add, DWORD remove=0) {
    DWORD symOptions = SymGetOptions();
    symOptions |= add;
    symOptions &= ~remove;
    SymSetOptions(symOptions);
}

class symbol { 
    typedef IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64 sym_type;
    sym_type *sym;
    static const int max_name_len = 1024;
public:
    symbol(HANDLE process, DWORD64 address) : sym((sym_type *)::operator new(sizeof(*sym) + max_name_len)) {
        memset(sym, '\0', sizeof(*sym) + max_name_len);
        sym->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(*sym);
        sym->MaxNameLength = max_name_len;
        DWORD64 displacement;

        if (!SymGetSymFromAddr64(process, address, &displacement, sym))
            throw(std::logic_error("Bad symbol"));
    }

    std::string name() { return std::string(sym->Name); }
    std::string undecorated_name() { 
        std::vector<char> und_name(max_name_len);
        UnDecorateSymbolName(sym->Name, &und_name[0], max_name_len, UNDNAME_COMPLETE);
        return std::string(&und_name[0], strlen(&und_name[0]));
    }
};

bool show_stack(std::ostream &os, HANDLE hThread, CONTEXT& c) {
    HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
    int frame_number=0;
    DWORD offset_from_symbol=0;
    IMAGEHLP_LINE64 line = {0};

    SymHandler handler(process);

    sym_options(SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES | SYMOPT_UNDNAME);

    void *base = load_modules_symbols(process, GetCurrentProcessId());

    STACKFRAME64 s = init_stack_frame(c);

    line.SizeOfStruct = sizeof line;

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *h = ImageNtHeader(base);
    DWORD image_type = h->FileHeader.Machine;

    do {
        if (!StackWalk64(image_type, process, hThread, &s, &c, NULL, SymFunctionTableAccess64, SymGetModuleBase64, NULL))
            return false;

        os << std::setw(3) << "\n" << frame_number << "\t";
        if ( s.AddrPC.Offset != 0 ) {
            std::cout << symbol(process, s.AddrPC.Offset).undecorated_name();

            if (SymGetLineFromAddr64( process, s.AddrPC.Offset, &offset_from_symbol, &line ) ) 
                    os << "\t" << line.FileName << "(" << line.LineNumber << ")";
        }
        else
            os << "(No Symbols: PC == 0)";
        ++frame_number;
    } while (s.AddrReturn.Offset != 0);
    return true;
}

class get_mod_info {
    HANDLE process;
    static const int buffer_length = 4096;
public:
    get_mod_info(HANDLE h) : process(h) {}

    module_data operator()(HMODULE module) { 
        module_data ret;
        char temp[buffer_length];
        MODULEINFO mi;

        GetModuleInformation(process, module, &mi, sizeof(mi));
        ret.base_address = mi.lpBaseOfDll;
        ret.load_size = mi.SizeOfImage;

        GetModuleFileNameEx(process, module, temp, sizeof(temp));
        ret.image_name = temp;
        GetModuleBaseName(process, module, temp, sizeof(temp));
        ret.module_name = temp;
        std::vector<char> img(ret.image_name.begin(), ret.image_name.end());
        std::vector<char> mod(ret.module_name.begin(), ret.module_name.end());
        SymLoadModule64(process, 0, &img[0], &mod[0], (DWORD64)ret.base_address, ret.load_size);
        return ret;
    }
};

void *load_modules_symbols(HANDLE process, DWORD pid) {
    ModuleList modules;

    DWORD cbNeeded;
    std::vector<HMODULE> module_handles(1);

    EnumProcessModules(process, &module_handles[0], module_handles.size() * sizeof(HMODULE), &cbNeeded);
    module_handles.resize(cbNeeded/sizeof(HMODULE));
    EnumProcessModules(process, &module_handles[0], module_handles.size() * sizeof(HMODULE), &cbNeeded);

    std::transform(module_handles.begin(), module_handles.end(), std::back_inserter(modules), get_mod_info(process));
    return modules[0].base_address;
}
```