# How do I retrieve file / function / line numbers from a PDB using the addresses in a client's call stack?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, pdb-files

I'm adding some crash reporting to my game in C++, using the [StackWalker library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack) for Windows. I'm assuming that when a client generates a call stack, it will print addresses rather than file / function names, etc.

How can I convert these addresses into something human readable? I will be saving the PDB files, but I've got no idea how to inspect them.

Comment: [Almost a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15373451/179910).

Answer (score 2):

"I'm assuming that when a client generates a call stack, it will print addresses rather than file / function names"

Why are you assuming this? The page you linked has a section entitled "Loading the modules and symbols." It seems like this library will use your symbols if you tell it where to load them from. Is this not the case?

Alternately, you could spit out a [process dump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360), and Visual Studio or windbg will know how to use it in combination with your symbol file(s).

If the library doesn't do what you want, though, and you still want to interact with your symbol files through custom code, you can go through [this mess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323) to dig out your symbols.

Comment: Right! I am assuming it cause I'm not planning on distributing PDBs with my build. In tests, if the PDBs aren't present, the program has no way to load the symbols. The bit about "Loading the modules" appears to be about the internal workings of the library. That said- thank you so much for your info! Probably just generating my own dump will be a much better solution.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It sounded like you were working up nice tools for internal QA. Dumps are a good idea for code in the wild.